# Angular Reactive FormGroup value changes is not emitting changes in observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms

I have a simple form that i have declared, and an observable assigned to it, the observable is mapped to return an object, i am logging the object in console before returning but the valuechanges never triggers.

```
comPlanForm= new FormGroup({
    commissionPlanType: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    commissionPlanName: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(150)]),
    commissionPlanDescription: new FormControl('', [Validators.maxLength(150)]),
    payoutSchedule: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    broker: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    trigger: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
     waitUntilDays: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    startDate: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    endDate: new FormControl('')});

comPlanForm$ = this.comPlanForm.valueChanges.pipe(
    map(value => { 
        const plan= new CommissionPlanRequest(null,null,value.commissionPlanName, value.commissionPlanDescription,
        value.commissionPlanType, value.startDate, value.endDate, value.payoutSchedule, value.broker, null,
        new PlanTrigger(null,value.waitUntilDays,value.trigger),[]) 
        return plan;
    }),
    tap(x=>console.log(x))
);
```

I dont have ngOnInit, I also tried placing the console.log into the map function itself no luck, any ideas on why my value changes is not triggering?

Comment: you aren't subscribing...

Comment: Subscription is not needed here

Comment: why wouldn't `subscribe` be needed?

Comment: You either need to directly subscribe (and clean up subscription once done or have a memory leak - see [this blog post](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0) ) or pipe `comPlanForm$` through the async pipe (which internally subscribes) in your template.

Comment: @AndrewAllen: I was missing the async pipe in the template, I dont know how i forgot that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

```
 this.comPlanForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value =>
  { 
    const plan= new CommissionPlanRequest(null,null,value.commissionPlanName, value.commissionPlanDescription,
    value.commissionPlanType, value.startDate, value.endDate, value.payoutSchedule, value.broker, null,
    new PlanTrigger(null,value.waitUntilDays,value.trigger),[]) 
    this.comPlanForm$ = plan;
}
```

);